# 2003 toyota camry engine problem?

Tags: engine, toyota, camry

So this happens since 2 months ago.. it has 123,000 miles on it. I normally wait until the engine arrow goes below 1( I am not an expert so my bad on wording). And it seems ok to drive. does not make too much noise.. anyone knows what this problem is??
here is a link that I videotaped this morning.

https://youtu.be/iTVC1o5orvk

Details about the car: switched starter( near the bottom of the car?) and battery about 3 months ago.
I rarely drive on the highway. I bought this car about a yr ago. It had 112,000 miles on it.

Comment: Welcome to the site. I didn't hear anything out of the ordinary. Sorry, but I don't know what the problem is. Can you explain in more detail what the problem is?

Comment: Thank you so much for ur reply. When I switch the gear to rear or driver, the engine vibrates so strong, I feel like i can't even drive it. I feel like something might come off inside the hood. I am a total beginner with the car , so i might be overreacting to it.  In the video, at 28 seconds, if you don't mind wacthing it with high volume, when i switch to D, the whole front part vibrates.  I guess my big question to ask is it it normal when i begin the car, the engine arrow(?) goes close to 2?  I can't recall this happening about a yr ago  but not too sure.

Comment: Have you ever had a tune up done on the car? Plugs & O2 sensors? Which engine is in the car? The Camry has at least one of each V6 and I4 engines. I'm not able to watch the video right now, so cannot tell if there's any dash lights showing?

Comment: Is it correct to assume this began when it got cold outside? And how long have you owned the car?

Comment: L.hawes I am not sure about weather effect. I think it was like this even before.  I owned this car about 13 months now.

Answer (score 2):

After watching the video again, it appears the car is idling high because it is cold (which is normal). You stated that you normally let it get below "1" and it seems to drive ok.

**This leads me to believe there is no problem.**

When you engage the transmission at this engine RPM, the brakes are holding the car back along with the additional energy of the high idle engine. This is also normal and does not hurt anything, it just causes some vibrations you are not used to.

This is only from what I can see and hear in the video. If you are truly concerned, ask a mechanic for advice.